# Express: Referencing the parent within the route definition for a child

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am currently studying https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial/, but am puzzled about the route definition for a child element. For example, in the following...

```
// create a new comment
router.post('/posts/:post/comments', function(req, res, next) {
  var comment = new Comment(req.body);
  comment.post = req.post;

  comment.save(function(err, comment){
    if(err){ return next(err); }

    req.post.comments.push(comment);
    req.post.save(function(err, post) {
      if(err){ return next(err); }

      res.json(comment);
    });
  });
});
```

... we are trying to define the route for adding a new comment for a particular post. As you can see, we are required to link the parent to the comment...

```
comment.post = req.post;
```

... and we are also required to, understandably, save the parent within the comment save function. However, when comes to updating the comment (i.e. increasing the upvotes for a comment) we are only required to do...

```
// upvote a comment
router.put('/posts/:post/comments/:comment/upvote', function(req, res, next) {
  req.comment.upvote(function(err, comment){
    if (err) { return next(err); }

    res.json(comment);
  });
});
```

... where 'upvote' is a custom schema method...

```
CommentSchema.methods.upvote = function(cb) {
  this.upvotes += 1;
  this.save(cb);
};
```

... why is that we are not required to reference the parent object 'post' here at all? I mean how does the system know exactly which comment to load? I understand that ':post' refers to the parent post, however, we are not even referencing that pre-loaded parent within the method... so how is it being used? Are the correct set of comments automatically loaded from the pre-loaded post parent object, without our need to do this explicitly?

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

according with the tutorial :

```
router.param('post', function(req, res, next, id) {
  var query = Post.findById(id);

  query.exec(function (err, post){
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!post) { return next(new Error('can\'t find post')); }

    req.post = post;
    return next();
  });
});
```

This code will take params from route: post/:post , so basically if you test the route : post/1 , it will set into request object(req) the post with id:1